# Regex to match the letter string group between 2 numbers

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match only the letter from the following string?

`RO41 RNCB 0089 0957 6044 0001                            FPS21098343`

What I want: `FPS`

What I'm trying [LINK](http://regexr.com/64vnh) : `[0-9]{4}\s*\S+\s+(\S+)`

What I get: `FPS21098343`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use `^[^a-zA-Z]*([A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: Would your strings always look like this? Do you need any other validation of this input? Otherwise just `[A-Z]+` would do.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: check my updated answer. I've edited the `RO34 XXXX 1212`... part

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```js
var String = "0258 6044 0001     FPS21098343";
var Reg = /^(?:\d{4} )+ *([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\d+)$/;
var Match = Reg.exec(String);
console.log(Match);
console.log(Match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match up to the first one or more letters in the following way:

```cs
^[^a-zA-Z]*([A-Za-z]+)
^.*?([A-Za-z]+)
^[\w\W]*?([A-Za-z]+)
(?s)^.*?([A-Za-z]+)
```

If the tool treats `^` as the start of a line, replace it with `\A` that always matches the start of string.

The point is to match

- `^` / `\A` - start of string
- `[^a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than letters
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - capture one or more letters into Group 1.

The `.*?` part matches any text (as short as possible) before the subsequent pattern(s). `(?s)` makes `.` match line break chars.

Replace `A-Za-z` in all the patterns with `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letters. Also, note that `[^\p{L}]` = `\P{L}`.

Answer (score 0):

To grep all the groups of letters that go in a row in any place in the string you can simply use:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group to get `FPS`:

```
\b[0-9]{4}\s+\S+\s+([A-Z]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b[0-9]{4}` A wordboundary to prevent a partial match, and match 4 digits
- `\s+\S+\s+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars between whitespace chars
- `([A-Z]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xw0I7v/1)

If the chars have to be followed by digits till the end of the string, you can add `\d+$` to the pattern:

```
\b[0-9]{4}\s+\S+\s+([A-Z]+)\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hul1eG/1)